# react native- how to add items separately when item is onpressed

Tags: react-native, select, map-function, touchableopacity, onpress

> I have been able to add item in onPress but it only shows the pressed item only. I want it to displays all the selected item in a row in the view beneath.

```
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);
 const numbers =['1','2','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19']
```

const onPress =(item)=>{
setText(<Text style={{textAlign:"center"}}>{item});
console.log(item)
};

```
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ScrollView>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent:"center"}}>
  {numbers.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.item}  onPress={()=>onPress(item)}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:"center"}} key={index}> {item}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
      )})}
      
          </View>
    <View style={styles.select}>{text}</View>

  </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

)
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtJh2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that your onPress will override the previous value instead of appending to it. To append previous values into your text, you will need to first destructure the text state in your onPress followed by the new number.

```
  const onPress = (item) => setText(oldText => {
    if (oldText.length < max) {
      return [...oldText, item]
    } else return oldText
  })
```

Comment: such a wonderful solution but i will like you to help me if i can select, for example only 2 numbers or 5 numbers or any from the list. thanks already

Comment: What do you mean by selecting only 2 numbers or 5 numbers or any from the list?

Comment: The arrays are from 1 to 19, and I am asking if there is a way I can make the user select maybe two or five numbers from among the arrays i provided by onPress. for example, a user can select any of the numbers but the selected numbers should not be more than five if it is set to select only five numbers.... I dont know if I make myself clear. please help me

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you can add in a validation to check if the length of the oldText array is less than the max input then it will append the latest value to the array, if not it will not do anything.

Comment: ohk, Let me try and see

Comment: everything is working fine but can you help to wrap the values passed with the same styles like the oldText??